# Transit Visa required through PEK (Beijing International Airport) for a passport holder of Kyrgyzstan?

Tags: visas, transit, beijing, kyrgyzstan, pek

I am really confused and looked at various websites, but do NOT have enough information about passport holders of Kyrgyzstan needing a transit visa if going through the PEK Aiport in Beijing. Do Kyrgyz passport holders need a transit visa if going through the PEK airport to get to Macau?

The flight are as follows:

Bishkek > Kazakhstan > Beijing > Macau (Destination)

Answer (score 2):

As a Kyrgyz passport holder, you can transit in PEK (or any airport in mainland China except XMN) without a visa for up to 24 hours. Your passport must be valid for at least 3 months from the arrival date in PEK, and you must already hold a confirmed onward ticket to Macau.

For any transit in mainland China, I recommend making sure your connection is not too tight as there is paperwork to complete and sometimes long queues.

I found the general visa information at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_China#24-hour_transit) and then used TIMATIC to verify it. You can currently access TIMATIC [here](http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/countryinfo.html) but since it's not supposed to be public (but rather just used by the airlines) the URLs tend to become outdated quickly.

The relevant "visa facility" from the TIMATIC listing is:

> - Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit
>     area of the airport and have documents required for the next
>     destination. (SEE NOTE 88975)
>
>   - This TWOV facility does not apply at Fuzhou (FOC),    Huangshan (TXN), Mudanjiang (MDG), Shenzhen (SZX), Urumqi    (URC) and Yanji
>       (YNJ).
>   - This TWOV facility does not apply to nationals of Syria    transiting through Guangzhou (CAN).
>   - This TWOV facility does not apply to nationals of    Afghanistan, Azerbaijan, Iran, Iraq, Kazakhstan,    Kyrgyzstan, Malaysia, Oman,
>       Pakistan, Saudi Arabia, Sri    Lanka, Syria, Thailand, Turkey,
>       Turkmenistan and Yemen    transiting through Xiamen (XMN).
>   - This TWOV facility does not apply to passengers with a    British passport with nationality  British National    (Overseas)".
>   - This TWOV facility does not apply to passengers with a    Chinese Taipei (on the cover: Republic of China Taiwan)    passport.
>   - This TWOV facility does not apply to passengers with a Hong    Kong (SAR China) passport.
>   - This TWOV facility does not apply to passengers with a    Macao (SAR China) passport.
>   - NOTE 88975: This TWOV facility does not apply when passengers arrive on a direct flight from USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. AND depart on a direct flight to USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. (e.g. JFK - PVG - GUM).

Note that *for the purpose of transit without a visa* in China, Macau is considered as a separate country.

Comment: Yes, I looked through the TIMATIC thing and was very confused. What part of where it says that Kyrgyz Passport holders can stay without a visa for up to 24 hours? Can you please highlight that part? Thanks

Comment: I added the particular relevant entry from TIMATIC. As you can see, it applies to most nationalities, with some exceptions. I also added a note about the status of Macau for the purpose of TWOV.